# Python: Import library from local folder without editing system path

Tags: python, python-import, matplotlib-basemap

I'm wondering whether it is possible to use classes and methods contained within a library without:

1. Importing the library through `pip install`
2. Moving folders into `site-packages`
3. Editing the system PATH

So far the answers I've seen on stack overflow use the methods listed above but my specific use-case requires that I don't `pip install` things and that the system PATH remains unchanged.

The specific library I'm interested in is `Basemap`

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Um, if your library provides a `setup.py`, you can install it this way.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to "install" the library. I want to be able to move my program from computer to computer to computer without having to worry about individually installing or tinkering with things.

Comment: You can't import modules without having installed them first, this no Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by installing `Basemap` and `pyproj` on a separate computer using `pip install`. I then took those folders contained within `Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages`, copied them over to the computer I can't edit stuff on and into the folder containing my main script.

From there I can call stuff pretty much like normal, I just changed `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` to `from basemap import Basemap`

Comment: You will easily miss some of basemap's dependencies:- proj4, geos, and pillow. Moreover, the path to basic map data for plotting is out of place, causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: I was able to move the required dependencies into a Resources folder and changed the calls from basemap's `__init__` script to call them from the appropriate paths. I recognize it's not an ideal solution but I have unideal problem, and the solution works. @swatchai

Answer (score 0):

Move your library to the `site-packages` folder (in your python install directory) and you should be able to import the modules normally from elsewhere, without having to change PATH.

Comment: I should have included in my question that I can't add things to `site-packages`. I've updated the main post.

Comment: @ArdaArslan see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)